# JW Player 7 with FancyBox 3 integration

Tags: jquery, fancybox, lightbox, jwplayer

I've been trying for the most of the afternoon but just can't get this to work. I'm trying to get JW PLayer v7 to work with FancyBox 3.

Code so far.. The fancybox works in terms of the  overlay but the video does not show

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<link  href="jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<script src="jwplayer-7.9.3.js"></script>
<script>jwplayer.key="key-in-here=="</script>

</head>

<body>

<a class="jwVideo" href="https://path-to-file.mp4">Preview</a>


<script>
$(function() { 

 $(".jwVideo").click(function(event) { //select class attribute jwVideo assigned to a tag

    $.fancybox.open({
        content: '<div id="video_container">Loading the player ...</div>',
        afterShow: function(){ 
            var playerInstance = jwplayer("video_container");
            playerInstance.setup({
               file: "http://path-to-s3-file.mp4"
            });
        }
    });

    event.preventDefault(); =
});

});
</script>
```

Would super appreciate some help. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe that hanging `=` in `event.preventDefault(); =` is making trouble

Comment: That wasn't in my actual code but my fault from being in there, sorry! Any other ideas? p.s Thanks for quick reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out the Fancybox documentation for v3 - implementation seems to have changed somewhat since earlier versions:

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#inline

Bearing that in mind, the following seems to work fine:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
 $(".jwVideoClick").click(function(event) {
   $.fancybox.open({
     src  : '<div style="width:400px;background-color:transparent;"><div id="video_container"></div></div>',
     type : 'inline',
     opts : {
       onComplete : function() {
         var playerInstance = jwplayer("video_container").setup({
           file: "http://path-to-s3-file.mp4",
           width:"100%",
           aspectratio:"16:9"
         });
       }
     }
  });    
 }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery expects you to run the `ready` function so scripts load in good synchrony - so try this changing these lines:

```
<script>
$(function() {
```

to

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
```

Comment: No such luck unfortunately. I did add type: 'mp4' and that made a small diffference in that FancyBox returned a differing message ("The requested content cannot be loaded") than without adding the type:'mp4'. Does that hint at anything?

Comment: Perhaps it is a mime-type mp4 configuration on the server you need.

Comment: A standalone video plays ok, i've put up my progress here view-source:https://johnmacpherson.com/jw/jwplayer-lightbox-THREE.html

Comment: Updated as suggested but still no joy. I've updated the live page with new jquery call. Appreciate the help so far. Be great if we could get this working.

Answer (score 0):

fancyBox v3.0 does not have "afterShow" callback, use "afterMove" or "onComplete" callbacks

Comment: I tried onComplete and afterMove. No joy. I've put my current code here https://johnmacpherson.com/jw/jwplayer-lightbox-THREE.html

Comment: Have you heard of Codepen of jsFiddle?